# IF, Else, ElseIF Loop within a certain Date

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I want to set the following condition but i can only get 2 condition to be done

The three condition are less than 7 days multiple by one value, the range between 2 dates multiply by one value and more than 30 days multiply by another value.

Not able to get all to work

Not sure what went wrong

```
' To create the following condition
 'If less than 7 days interest = 0%
' if 8 to 30 days interest = 7%
 'if more than 31 days interest = 9%

Sub Workbook_Open()

For i = 1 To 3 'Rows.Count
xdate = Cells(i, 1)

nulldate = DateAdd("d", -7, Date)
irate7late = DateAdd("d", -8, Date)
irate7early = DateAdd("d", -30, Date)


If Day(nulldate) < Day(xdate) Then
    result = Cells(i, 2) * 1
ElseIf Day(irate7early) <= Day(xdate) And Day(xdate) <= Day(irate7late) Then
            '30/9/2015      20/10/2015      20/10/2015      22/10/2015
    result = Cells(i, 2) * 1.07

ElseIf Day(irate7early) > Day(xdate) Then
    result = Cells(i, 2) * 1.09
End If

Cells(i, 3).Value = result

Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this below code for your requirement

```
 Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim diffdate As Variant

For i = 1 To 3 'Rows.Count

      xdate = Cells(i, 1).Value
      diffdate = (DateDiff("d", xdate, Now()))

        If diffdate < 7 Then
            result = Cells(i, 2) * 1
        ElseIf diffdate < 31 And diffdate > 7 Then
            result = Cells(i, 2) * 1.07
        Else
            result = Cells(i, 2) * 1.09
        End If

    Cells(i, 3).Value = result

Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Reversing your test may simplify them sometimes:

```
Sub Workbook_Open()

    Dim delta as Long
    Dim xdate as Date
    For i = 1 To 3 'Rows.Count
        xdate = Cells(i, 1).Value
        delta = DateDiff("d", xdate, Date)

        If delta > 30 Then
            Cells(i,3).Value = Cells(i,2).Value * 1.09
        ElseIf delta > 7 Then
            Cells(i,3).Value = Cells(i,2).Value * 1.07
        Else 'delta <= 7
            Cells(i,3).Value = Cells(i,2).Value
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

And don't forget `Option Explicit`, it may save you a lot of time in debugging.